# Server/Client Android to PC communication issue

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

Im trying to write a program using sockets having an android phone as the client and my PC as the server i found and slightly modified code for both sides and my server code works but i can't get the client activity to and i don't know acutally how to get the to programs to talk i want to basically be able to have either side input text and have it sent and set visable to the other i know how much of a stickler you guys are for questions so... How do i get these to communicate?

Client code (The emulator crashes before i can even begin to see the problem)

```
package com.example.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText serverIp;

    private Button connectPhones;

    private String serverIpAddress = "";

    private boolean connected = false;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.client);

        serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
        connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
        connectPhones.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) connectListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!connected) {
                serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
                if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 9999);
                connected = true;
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                    .getOutputStream())), true);
                            // where you issue the commands
                            out.println("Hey Server!");
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the Server code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

/**
 * Simple server using Java Sockets.
 * @author Jonathan Engelsma (http://www.cis.gvsu.edu/~engelsma)
 *
 */
public class Server {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // First we create a server socket and bind it to port 9999.
        ServerSocket myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);


        // wait for an incoming connection... 
        System.out.println("Server is waiting for an incoming connection on host=" 
                + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() 
                + " port=" + myServerSocket.getLocalPort());
        Socket skt = myServerSocket.accept();

        // ok, got a connection.  Let's use java.io.* niceties to read and write from the connection.
        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream myOutput = new PrintStream(skt.getOutputStream());  

        // attempt to read input from the stream.
        String buf = myInput.readLine();

        // if we got input, print it out and write a message back to the remote client..
        if (buf != null) {
            System.out.println("Server read: [" + buf + "]");
            myOutput.print("got it");
        }

        // close the connection.
        skt.close();
        System.out.println("Server is exiting");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Whoops, something bad happened!  I'm outta here.");
    }



}
```

}

Comment: What's it say when it crashes?  Does it crash when you try to connect? or when the activity launches?

Comment: it says the program was forced to close the error was from the emulator not eclipse it seems to be a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Are you using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In the Android Manifest? That could cause your problem.

Comment: put in a break point in both your client piece and server piece and then step through your code, this should let you know which call it is breaking on. Surround with a try/catch. With sockets, you can use  catch (UnknownHostException e) and catch (IOException e). Remember though that if this is inside another try/catch it will default to the outer catch(Exception e) which will not give you enough information to debug the problem. Use LogCat as well, red statements indicate a problem. Let us know the exceptions thrown and the LogCat output and it should be easy to find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ICS or JB, then you are probably being restricted from opening network connections from within your main activity.  you will get an opaque error message regarding network permissions.

i cant repost my answer to another quite similar StackOverflow question here (it is considered spamming by moderators), but you can [CHECK IT OUT HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249385/1166727).

i posted a functional send and receive socket connector client using asynctask there.